# Datediff seconds return error

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a variable `$date="2016-10-09 10:44:03";` and a list of messages ordered by `date_post` ( `TIMESTAMP CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`). (`$date` is always lower than `date_post` for seconds)

I want to return results from

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(second, $date,date_post) AS duration 
FROM messages 
WHERE condition
```

but it returns error

> supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ....

It is suppossed to return a number, but it just return error. According to the sintax, `$date` must be written first in `DATEDIFF`. I tried to use `CAST($date)`, but nothing. Do I need to modify  `$date` before using it? If I work with `DATEDIFF(date_post,date_post)` returns `0`, but with `$date` returns error

Comment: You've answered the question yourself when you mention about the syntax because MySQL DATEDIFF syntax is: `DATEDIFF($date, date_post)` in your case. You don't specify an interval.

Comment: using `DATEDIFF($date, date_post)` returns error as well. I is supposed to return the interval of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the difference in seconds, the easiest way is to use `to_seconds()`:

```
SELECT m.*,
       ( to_seconds(date_post) - to_seconds($date) )AS duration 
FROM messages m
WHERE condition;
```

The function you are using is a SQL Server functions.  In MySQL, `datediff()` returns the difference between two dates in days.

Comment: thanks but, my server works with `mySQL 4.x.x`, not recongnize `to_seconds()`

Comment: It'll be `TIME_TO_SEC` for earlier MySQL versions. But you'll have to extract the `time` part of the date to do so. Not certain if earlier versions support `TIMESTAMPDIFF` or not, but that allows you to specify the interval.